# fabric.js: How to clip my number or alphabet sprite?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

[image: sprite.png]

I have a sprite(36hx360w) of numbers,
and I want to clip it to 0, 1, 2, ..., 9, making 10 fabric.Image objects, whose width is 36px and height is 36px.
[image: sprite]

This is how I've tried, but it doesn't work as I expected.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(my_sprite, function(img) {
  canvas.add(img);
  canvas.renderAll();
},{
  width:360,
  height:36,
  top:0,
  left:0,
  clipTo:function(ctx){
    ctx.rect(0,0,36,36);
  }
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/fLh5a7k9/

Comment: I have created something that might fit what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/172/.

Comment: Thank you very much! it is what i want! why not write an answer? I will choose it as the best answer:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments:

Rewrite your code like this:

```
(function() {
    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        drawRect(canvas, i);
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
})();

function drawRect(canvas, i){    
        fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGOgp.png', function(img) {
        canvas.add(img);  
    },{
        width:360,
        height:36,
        top: 36 * i,
        left: -( 36 * i ),
        clipTo:function(ctx){
            ctx.rect(-180 + 36 * i, -18 , 36, 36);
    }
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/172/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fabric.Sprite.fromURL` which lets you create sprites from fabric.js. It will also offer other helpers for creating and managing sprites

See more details in http://fabricjs.com/animated-sprite/

Comment: I have tried Animated Sprite, but it is for animation sprite, not for a static one.

Comment: If you posted a jsfiddle.net example it would be easier to figure out